# Convert Drawing.Color into HTML color value

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I asked a question about this already, but I wrong-phrased it.

I have a method `GetRandColor()` on the server that returns a `System.Drawing.Color` object.

What I want is to be able to set html attributes using this when the page loads. So as an example,

```
<html>
<body bgcolor="#GetRandColor()">
<h1>Hello world!</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: (I suspect that a few brackets are missing in the above. Also, likely time to start thinking about abandoning `bgcolor` ..)

Comment: If your question is converting a color to a hex string you can use `System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToHtml(myColor);`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can't return a `System.Drawing.Color` object from your function because browsers only understand text. So instead, you should return the string representation of the color, be in RGB, HEX format or what have you.

Your method then should look like this:

```
 protected string GetRandColor()
 {
     return ColorTranslator.ToHtml(Color.Red);
 }
```

And you can set the background of your form as so:

```
<body style="background-color:<%=GetRandColor()%>;">
```

Answer (score 2):

If GetRandColor() is in a static class, this should work:

```
<body bgcolor="<%= System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToHtml(ClassName.GetRandColor()) %>">
```

You may need to add the class' namespacess before the class name.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with the help of inline expression: **[Inline expressions in the .NET Framework](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976112)**

**Displaying expression** `(<%= ... %>)`

```
bgcolor="<%= System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToHtml(GetRandColor()) %>"
```

Comment: Useful link but the answer is incorrect. There's no data binding here and therefore using a data-binding expression will not work.

Comment: I just reverted back..@Icarus

Answer (score 1):

You can use **ColorTranslator** to convert Drawing.Color to HTML color value. For example,

```
System.Drawing.Color c = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#F5F7F8"); 

String strHtmlColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToHtml(c);
```

This link will help you too : msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.colortranslator.fromhtml.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
public string GetRandHtmlColor(){

    System.Drawing.Color c = GetRandColor();
    return System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToHtml(c);
}
```